# PropertyInfo.GetValue(object obj, object[] index) throwing 'Target' exception

Tags: c#, generics, propertyinfo

I need a generic list with extended search mechanism, so i have created a generic list (base `List<T>`) with an addirional indexer. So in this, if T is an object, then the list allows to fetch the item based on a field. Here is the Sample code

```
public class cStudent
    {
      public Int32 Age { get; set; }
      public String Name { get; set; }
    }

TestList<cStudent> l_objTestList = new TestList<cStudent>();
l_objTestList.Add(new cStudent { Age = 25, Name = "Pramodh" });
l_objTestList.Add(new cStudent { Age = 28, Name = "Sumodh" });
cStudent l_objDetails = l_objTestList["Name", "Pramodh"];
```

**And my genereic list**

```
class TestList<T> : List<T>
    {
          public T this[String p_strVariableName, String p_strVariableValue]
           {
             get
               {
                 for (Int32 l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < this.Count; l_nIndex++)
                  {
                       PropertyInfo l_objPropertyInfo = (typeof(T)).GetProperty(p_strVariableName);
                       object l_obj = l_objPropertyInfo.GetValue("Name", null);  // Wrong Statement -------> 1                
                  }
                return default(T);
               }
           }
    }
```

But i can not get the value of the property, its throwing 'Target Exception'.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code will need to be something like this...

```
object l_obj = l_objPropertyInfo.GetValue("Name", null);
```

=>

```
object l_obj = l_objPropertyInfo.GetValue(this[l_nIndex], null);
```

The first argument to the GetValue function is the object instance you want to retrieve the value of the property from.